# What is the meaning of 振り切って in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm currently translating this video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMj_aFUjTwk

In the play, this actor is playing a boy, who has Chuunibyou.

At 0:15 he said

> しっかり、え、中二病をこじらせて**振り切って**演じたいと思います。

According to [Jishou](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A%E5%88%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6),

> 振り切る = to shake off/ to swing completely

so I was wondering what does it mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

振り切った演技 is used to describe an actor has completely gotten into a character and played the role convincingly. 迫真の演技 is similar, but 振り切った演技 tends to be used for a difficult and eccentric character. Playing a 中二病 boy typically requires 振り切った演技 because, you know, it's a bit embarrassing and eccentric role.

This 振り切る can be understood either as "to shake off your ordinary way of thinking and become unbound by anxiety and embarrassment" or "to fully put your effort into the character". 振る can mean to put/direct/assign (energy, workload, role, number, etc) to something/someone. 切る adds the meaning of "completely". (gamer's example: パラメータをSTRに振り切る "to assign all parameters to strength")

Comment: May I also ask about しっかり in this particular context? There seems to be a lot of meaning on [Jishou](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%A2%BA%E3%82%8A) Can "I **definitely** want to...." be used in this case?

Comment: The third definition on jisho (fully, hardly, well, etc) applies for this しっかり.

Answer (score 0):

He is referring to feelings of embarrassment (or any other negative feelings) that may be caused in the future when going through acting (performing) the role. He saids that he will suck it up and get it done.